# Turn on sql highlighting for dollar-quoted strings?

Tags: intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting

So I need to write some dynamic sql, e.g.

```sql
-- expects stmt to contain '%1$I' wherever the table name should be inserted
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION executeForEachFooBarTable(stmt TEXT) RETURNS VOID AS $function$
DECLARE
    foobar TEXT;
    foobar_tables TEXT[] := array['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'bam'];
BEGIN
    FOREACH foobar IN ARRAY foobar_tables LOOP
            EXECUTE format(stmt, foobar);
        END LOOP;
END $function$
LANGUAGE plpsql VOLATILE;

DO $addSunshineColumnToFoobarTables$ BEGIN
    PERFORM executeForEachFooBarTable($$
        ALTER TABLE %1$I
            ADD COLUMN is_sun_shining BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE
        ;
        UPDATE f
            SET f.is_sun_shining = w.is_sunny
            FROM %1$I f
                LEFT JOIN weather_station w ON f.weather_station_id = w.id
        ;
    $$);
END $addSunshineColumnToFoobarTables$;
```

IntelliJ, insists that the statement is a string (and it's correct in that, granted), and displays it in all-green.

Is there any way to make it instead highlight the syntax within the string? I think there are a couple SQL editors out there that would do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Language Injection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-language-injections.html) feature (from Alt+Enter popup):

[image]

Comment: Not perfect because I need to do it for every string and it of course doesn't know how to deal with placeholders like `%1$I`, which occasionally breaks the highlighting, but I'll take it. :) Thank you very much.